# Can I use pacman package manager instead of apt in ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management

Can I use `pacman` package manager instead of `apt` in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, but you're not going to get the arch repositories with it. You'll be much better off ditching ubuntu and installing a proper arch-based linux.

Answer (score 5):

Deb-pacman is a Bash script that emulates the functionality of Pacman (the package manager for Arch Linux and its variants). Using Deb-pacman, you can use the pacman commands in a Debian-based system the same way as you use them under Arch Linux to install, update, upgrade and remove packages. You can simply invoke `pacman` instead of `apt` command in your Ubuntu system. Deb-pacman emulates Arch Linux's Pacman package manager feel for Debian users who may prefer the style of pacman over apt. This can be helpful for those who got used to pacman in Arch Linux.

To install deb-pacman open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
wget https://gitlab.com/TriVoxel/deb-pacman/uploads/460d83f8711c1ab5e16065e57e7eeabc/deb-pacman-2.0-0.deb  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install ./deb-pacman_2.0-0.deb
```